# Wann nutzt man "es" oder "das" und wann "die" oder "der" bei Bezug auf früheren Satz?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Hier ein Beispiel zu meiner Frage:

> Ich habe jeden Tag eine Tablette genommen. Aber es hat nichts genützt.

Warum wird hier "es" benutzt? Weil *Tablette* den Artikel "die" hat?

Und könnte man auch "das" anstelle von "es" nutzen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das Pronomen "es" bezieht sich in dem Fall nicht auf die Tablette, sondern auf den ganzen Vorgang, also auf das Nehmen einer Tablette jeden Tag. Deshalb benutzt man da "es".

Es ist ja nicht eine einzelne Tablette, die nichts genutzt hat.

"Das" geht auch, würde ich hier sogar besser finden. Ich kenne aber den Kontext auch nicht genau.

Answer (score 2):

*"Es"* in this sentence refers to the **event** of taking one pill each day. Therefore it's also valid to use **"das"** instead of **"es"**, at least in this case.

You could still say **"Aber sie hat nichts genützt"**, if you like to refer to the pill, that would still be a correct sentence (but slightly different meaning). However, in this case, it would be more common to say "Sie hat nicht gewirkt" or "Sie hat nicht geholfen".

Also, be aware that you should concatenate both sentences from your example into one:
**"Ich habe jeden Tag eine Tablette genommen, aber es hat nichts genützt."**

Comment: Du widersprichst Dir selbst. Du stellst richtig fest, dass "es" sich auf das Einnehmen der Tabletten (jeden Tag eine) bezieht. "Sie" hat überhaupt kein Element im vorherigen Satz, auf das sich singular femininum beziehen könnten. "Sie haben nichts genützt" könnte man freilich sagen. Oder auf die Aussage "Ich habe eine Kopfschmerztablette genommen" - darauf kann folgen "Sie hat nichts genutzt."